# How get maximum Number of traversal for a particular node in ArangoDB?

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I wanted to find out the maximum number of depth or traversal a node can have.
Cuurently for a node i dont know how much depth does that particular node have and i want to find it out.

I was trying by giving 'n' a very large number say 999999 and iterating it in the below query to find where the below query will give an empty output and then the max depth would be n-1.

This is taking way too long.

```
FOR v, e, p IN n..n INBOUND 'all_company_data/6065e30a85a7200b323a317f' 
    GRAPH Final_graph
    OPTIONS {bfs: true, uniqueVertices: 'global', maxIterations: 100000}
    LIMIT 100 
    RETURN p
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that if and how this can be computed in acceptable time depends on the structure of your graph - it would need to be a directed acyclic graph.  Arangodb itself does not implement a longest graph algorithm, because it cannot be done in the generell case, AFAIU.  See wikipedia for a discussion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: So we dont know the second vertex that is we only know the starting vertes.
Hence finding longest path between 2 vertices wont be relevant.

Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Your problem is discussed in the section acyclic graphs in the linked wikipedia article; I'm sorry that i can be not of more help.